# Cannot push to a shared repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, ssh-keys

My friend has shared with me a bitbucket repository. I cloned it on my machine. Each time that I want to push something, I receive the following error:

```
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I looked for a potential issue and realized the ssh-key could be the most probable one.
After following the steps [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) and [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/), I still could not resolve this issue.

So, this time I created a new repository. After cloning, I tried to push something to it, and it worked properly. Now, I am wondering what else I should do.

Comment: Are you sure your friend gave you write access to the repository? If you can clone and pull but not push, this would indicate that you do not have write access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe you are right, and it is the reason.